# Formtastic prints a number in nested form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, formtastic

I have this form

```
- semantic_form_for :qualification,  :url => { :controller => 'qualifications', :action => 'add_students' } do |form|
- form.inputs do
  = form.input :name, :label => "Course Title"
  = form.input :course_type, :collection => Qualification::COURSE_TYPES
  = form.input :graduate_date, :label => "Course Start Date", :start_year => pdc_start_year, :end_year => 1972, :discard_day => true
  = form.input :location, :label => "Course Location"
  = form.semantic_fields_for :user do |student|
    = student.input :first_name
    = student.input :last_name
= form.submit 'Add Students'
```

and it creates before the button this

1

I see this 1 generated but I would like to remove it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just guessing here that you're using rails 2?

```
= form.semantic_fields_for :user do |student|
```

should be

```
- form.semantic_fields_for :user do |student|
```